# how to set request timeout in rails ( thin or webrick server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, request

When I upload a big file to rails server, I always get a request timeout error.  I don't know where to change the request timeout value.

Answer (score 8):

For webrick there is a file called `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/config.rb`.

Location may differ based on your version and install method.  In that file there is a line:

`:RequestTimeout => 30` that can be modified.

And in thin, `thin -t 60` makes the timeout 60 seconds, the default is 30